# c++ c# equivaltent object instance

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, reference

C#

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

C++

```
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
```

Is the C# code internally equivaltent to the C++ code? Is the myClass internally in C# code the referent or a pointer?

Comment: I'm not sure if you should compare them like this. Very crudely, in C++ you have references, pointers and values (that I know of), in C# you have classes and structs. You should learn to use them each accordingly.They all have different usages

Comment: @Default In C# we typically refer to them as "reference types" and "value types"

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that is definitely a better wording! (too late to edit though)

Comment: Yes, it is a plain pointer, the exact flavor that C++ uses.  C# could not approximate C++ perf if that was not the case.  The only extra detail is that the garbage collector can find it back.  In C++ the programmer has to find it back and call the delete operator explicitly.  Or call in the help of another class to get that done, that's where perf starts to suffer.

Answer (score 2):

A more accurate way to express the intent of this C# code

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

in C++ might be

```
auto myClass = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

(or perhaps `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClass(new MyClass());`).

Of course, C# uses something **completely** different than `std::shared_ptr` (garbage collection), but what a programmer sees is largely the same—at least for this very simple example.

Your original C++ code creates a memory leak, which can't happen as easily in C#.

Comment: In addition, the big difference is you have to remove the allocated memory in C++ (MANUAL), but C# is managing the allocated memory (AUTOMATIC).

Answer (score 1):

They are not *exactly* equivalent, since C# objects are tracked by the garbage collector ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t81zye4(v=vs.71).aspx)). To get similar functionality in C++, you would need to use a `shared_ptr`.

From the standpoint of *using* them however, the same concepts apply. Changes made through a reference will propagate to other references that "point" to the same object, etc.

Comment: C# uses garbage collection, not reference counting.

Comment: "References are basically just pointers". You mean internally, right, because a reference is const and semantically it should also be used differently? "in C++, an auto_ptr would be basically the same". You write basically, that irritates me. Is in C# the myClass now a semantically reference or a pointer/shared_ptr?

Comment: @SLaks My apologies, apparently the framework is in fact using some sort of other algorithm

Comment: @Gernot Not sure they are any more const than pointers (especially considering that you can use `ref` with them). I tried to reword the answer, feel free to let me know if I missed something else

Comment: maybe not suggest [`auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) since it's deprecated in C++11?